# Iterate through dynamic table rows using serenity screenplay

Tags: java, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

What is the best way to deal with dynamic web table using serenity screenplay?
in selenium I use to do like,

```
List <webelement> rows = wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]"));
```

Comment: which part in your locator is dynamic? Try this one https://serenity-bdd.github.io/docs/screenplay/screenplay_webdriver#using-dynamic-targets

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 table rows are going to be dynamic as per filter selection and thanks for the link.